# How create an organization in CKAN with an image through the API lik it's possible with web interface

Tags: ckan

In CKAN when creating an organization with the web interface, it's possible to provide an image_url or select a image on our local disk.
With this 2nd choice, the image is uploaded and the organisation has the link to the image.

With the [CKAN API](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.create.organization_create) there is only a parameter `image_url`, and I can't find a solution to upload an image with the API.

How can I upload an image to provide the `image_url` paramater to the API ?

I tried to look for the API, but I only found resource API that is not adapted for this need.
And I found nothing in the doc or forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to my question:

1. Create an organisation `myorg` without image (necessary for the step 2)
2. Create a dataset attached to the previous organisation

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5001/api/3/action/package_create' \
--form 'name="myds"' \
--form 'owner_org="myorg"'
```

3. Upload the image using the Filestore api:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5001/api/3/action/resource_create' \
--form 'package_id="myds"' \
--form 'upload=@"./myimage.jpg"' \
--form 'name="myimage.jpg"'
```

Retrieve the URL from the response

You now have an URL for the resource, and you can use it to update the organisation or create a new one.